# How to insert a sublayer in swift?

Tags: swift

I am creating a view and adding a gradient layer to it.

I have this:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


let rect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)

var vista : UIView = init(frame: rect)

let gradient : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = vista.bounds

let cor1 = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
let cor2 = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

let arrayColors = [cor1, cor2]

gradient.colors = arrayColors
```

now I have to do this

```
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

How do I do that in swift?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the following snippet

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(yourLayer, atIndex: yourIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly but strangely, I was trying to guess the command by typing view.layer.insert and pressing tab, to see if autosuggest would come with something, but nothing came, so I thought I was on the wrong path. BTW, what is the best way to discover a command like this when you don't know?

Comment: You could command+click on layer and then command+click on CALayer (or command+shift+o and type CALayer) to get to CALayer swift representation of the objc header file

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex:0)
```

Note that whenever you're editing Swift code, you can command-click on a symbol from the frameworks to see a Swift-ified version of that API's header file. Also, the documentation [online](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/insertSublayer%3aatIndex%3a) and in Xcode shows Swift syntax for all the APIs it covers.