# How to represent an array of DSPDoubleSplitComplex numbers in the header of functions, as input or output?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I am new to swift. I have this line of code inside a function...

```
var complexBuffer = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: reals.baseAddress!, imagp: imags.baseAddress!)
```

This function must return an array of `complexBuffer` elements.

How do I write the function header to accomplish that?

```
func myFunction () -> ??????? array of DSPSoubleSplitComplex  {

}
```

and how to I write the header of the next function receiving it.

for example...

```
let result = myFunction ()
self.secondFunction (result)

func secondFunction (??????? array of DSPSoubleSplitComplex) {
}
```

Comment: New to Swift? You are posting about Swift [since 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24111612/1187415) :)

Comment: Isn't it simply `func myFunction () -> DSPDoubleSplitComplex`  ? Do you want to return a DSPDoubleSplitComplex, or an array of DSPDoubleSplitComplex?

Comment: I want to receive and to return an array of DSPDoubleSplitComplex

Comment: @MartinR - I start doing some learning in 2014. Never used swift since, cause my job required Objective-C. Five years and four versions later I am back, now to create my first app using swift.

Comment: That would be `func myFunction () -> [DSPDoubleSplitComplex]`. – But you said *“This function must return this complexBuffer,”* and `complexBuffer` is a DSPDoubleSplitComplex, not an array of DSPDoubleSplitComplex. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Then `func myFunction () -> [DSPDoubleSplitComplex]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any Swift type `T`, `[T]` is the type of an *array containing elements of type T.* An equivalent notation is `Array<T>`.

Therefore the signature of a function returning an array of DSPDoubleSplitComplex is

```
func myFunction(...) -> [DSPDoubleSplitComplex]
```

and the signature of a function taking an array of DSPDoubleSplitComplex as argument is (with an arbitrarily chosen parameter name)

```
func secondFunction(array: [DSPDoubleSplitComplex], ...)
```